# Annotate queryset models with fields from "through" model

Tags: python, django

This seems like it should be easy, but I've been unable to find an answer despite lots of googling.

I have two models joined by a many-to-many relationship through a third model that has some additional fields.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='projects', through='UserProject')

    # additional project fields

class UserProject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_used = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

what I want is to be able to access a given user's projects along with the `favorite` and `last_used` fields for that user for each project.

I cannot figure out how to do that using annotations or any other method on a call to `user.projects`. If I call the through relationship directly (i.e., `user.userproject_set`), I can add fields from the project with a single sql query by calling, e.g., `user.userproject_set.select_related('project').annotate(name='project.name')`, but then the models in the resulting queryset are UserProjects, not Projects, which is not what I want.

Writing a sql query to do what I want would be trivial (it would basically be the same query Django produces to join the Project fields to the UserProject queryset). Is there a way to get Django to add fields from the through table to the models in a queryset accessed through one side of a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the related name to access the related objects. Using this, you should get `Project` objects:

```
user.projects.all()
```

Comment: What I want is the Project annotated with the fields from the intermediate table for the user through which the project was accessed. `user.projects.all()` will give me Project models without annotations. Calling `user.projects.get(pk=3).userproject_set.get(pk=user.pk).favorite ` will give me access to the field I want, but I want to add it to the Project instance as an annotation. What I want is to be able to do something like `user.projects.annotate(favorite=“userproject_set[user].favorite”).all()`, but that syntax doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different options, including FilterRelation, I found a way to get what I wanted by using the QuerySet's `extra` method to add the fields I want from the intermediate table:

```
user.projects.extra(select={
    'favorite': 'app_userproject.favorite',
    'last_used': 'app_userproject.last_used'
})
```

No additional SQL queries/database hits, no new joins, and no changes to the `where` clause are required, because the relevant joins and conditions are already part of the query Django constructs to retrieve the child models from the many-to-many relationship. Which is why it seems like there should be some way to do this in Django without having to resort to `extra` -- which Django is [threatening to deprecate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra).